# Is there a way to measure tension around a circular membrane?

Tags: forces

I'm trying to find a way to measure tension force at each point (tuning screw) of a snare drum head.[image: Snare drum] The little screws on the rim are the tuning screws. Obviously, as the screws are tightened the tension at each screw increases, but is there any way to calculate a numerical value for tension at each tuning screw? I've done some research and the only thing I've found is tension on a circular membrane, but all documents that I've found are way to complex for my understanding. Please simplify them if they are related.

I'm a physics amateur (11th grade, 16) so please be nice :) This is also my first post on Physics Stack Exchange so I apologize if anything in my post is unorthodox.

Comment: You can get small torque wrenches which you could use... this would enable you to get the same torque on ech screw, see https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/SNAP-ON-INDUSTRIAL-BRANDS-Torque-Screwdriver-1-4-5-to-40-in-lb-401SM/253781172125?epid=2254350278&hash=item3b16895f9d:g:1zUAAOSwNepcGepz as an example.

Comment: The tension in the screw is going to be a complicated combination of the tension in the drum membrane and the force applied to the body of the drum. That's going to be very difficult to resolve. I'm guessing the usual procedure is to adjust the screw until the sound the drum makes is correct.

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to measure the tension?

Comment: @puppetsock is there a way to just find tension in the drum membrane for each screw?

Comment: @nicoguaro I'm doing a lab based on tension in the membrane and frequency of the sound that the drumhead makes.

Comment: If you can reference the documents you mention it would be easier to help. Also, a snare drum does not produce a pitched sound.